# Want p to stay in the same position

Tags: html, css

When I click the buttons, there is some text added to the ul which is at the top left.

my p is on the right of the page and it moves down as more text(row)s are added. I want it to stay there. What code should i add?

```
    <ul id="elementlist">
    </ul>

    <button onclick="addWater()"> Add Water  </button>
    <button onclick="addFire()"> Add Fire  </button>



    <div style="float:right;">
    <p>aaaa</p>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">



function addWater() {
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("elementlist").appendChild(node);
}

function addFire() {
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("Fire");
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("elementlist").appendChild(node);
}




</script>
```

Comment: I've tried position: absolute didn't work.

Comment: what do you mean by stay there?

Comment: it's a js code when i click the button there is like rows added to the ul as texts, but when they are added the p moves down, i'll post the js code too just to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `<p>` tag inside a custom div and apply `position: fixed` into that div and adjust `top` and `right` to make it work.

```css
.custom-pos {
   position: fixed;
   right: 2%;
   top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="elementlist">
</ul>

<button onclick="addWater()"> Add Water  </button>
<button onclick="addFire()"> Add Fire  </button>



<div class="custom-pos">
<p>aaaa</p>
</div>
```

Comment: it worked thanks but is there a way to do it without using fixed

Comment: oh nvm! I got it, i just changed 'fixed' into 'absolute' wow thanks nice code

Answer (score 0):

You could use position fixed (or absolute) as suggested,
or you can achieve the same using flexbox, if you can avoid supporting old browsers:

```js
function addWater() {
  var node = document.createElement("LI");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("elementlist").appendChild(node);
}

function addFire() {
  var node = document.createElement("LI");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("Fire");
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("elementlist").appendChild(node);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.content {
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
.sidebar {
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <main class="content">
    <ul id="elementlist">
    </ul>
    <button onclick="addWater()">Add Water</button>
    <button onclick="addFire()">Add Fire</button>
  </main>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <p>aaaa</p>
  </div>
</div>
```